# How do energy blasts work?

Tags: squadron-uk

I just can't get my head around energy blasts.  I understand the range is equal to your psyche and the target area is a total of 9. Be this in a beam, wall or area blast.

What I'm having trouble with is the number of dice you get, how quickly you get them back and if you can use lower amounts of dice when attacking.

I'm keen to run this game, but feel that just not using beams blasts and Rays will be missing a massive part of the superhero experience.

Comment: I asked Simon Burley to nip across and answer this question - if only for completeness! I'm sure he'll be along soon.